# Design for Graphic Rendering in Java with Unspecified Update Reasons (Hierarchical)

Tags: java, design-patterns, renderer

- Original Question

  I'm working for graphic rendering part of my program, and got into
  several severe problems with my previous design.

  So, I want to ask how to design structures of renderers and models.
  Or is there specific design pattern to handle this case?

  Currently I have hierarchical implementations of

  - Renderers (Graphics)
  - Models (Data to Render, Receive Updates)

  I accepted hierarchy since rendered contents can be classified, and
  should be managed separately.

  There are several limiting conditions:

  1. Rendering is done on rendering loop.
  2. There could be many types of renderers and models, and the design should not be aware of them.
  3. There could be various reasons to update models.

     1. Update reasons should not be specified in the design itself, since various reasons can be added.
     2. Models are aware of possible update reasons for itself.
  4. Renderers have Render Passes and Render Helpers.

     1. Types of Render Passes are dependent to the Classes(groups) of renderers.
     2. Render Helpers should be provided, and each renderer should be able to use different version of it.

---

**EDIT:** Code to explain current situation.

Renderer:

```
public interface IRenderer<Settings, Pass, Model, Helper> {
    public void initialize(Settings settings);
    public void preRender(Settings settings, Helper info);
    public void renderPass(Model model, Pass pass, Helper info);
    public void postRender(Settings settings, Helper info);
}
```

Model:

```
public interface IModel<Settings, UpdateInfo> {
    public void initialize(Settings settings);
    public void update(Settings settings, UpdateInfo update);
}
```

---

**EDIT2:**
Since **update reasons** are not specified and can contain various information, I have problem with updating model.

Specifically, the type of update information varies for each update reason, which makes it hard to check the types in compile time.

(If this helps, update information will contain

- changed settings for settings change
- updated data for user interaction
- spontaneous changes for system loop

and so on)

How should I control update part here? Is there good design pattern to solve this problem and let the code cleaner?

Comment: The question is very vague and very broad. Maybe adding some pseudocode of what you want to achieve might help, or if you described what does and what doesn't work with the current design.

Comment: @Marco13 Thanks, I'd give more details in the question.